# apache pdfbox-PDType1Font (HELVETICA) encode

Tags: java, pdfbox

**My LOG**

exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0009 ('controlHT') is not available in this font Helvetica (generic: ArialMT) encoding: WinAnsiEncoding] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0009 ('controlHT') is not available in this font Helvetica (generic: ArialMT) encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You simply try to draw a character for which the font does not contain a glyph. In your case it is a control character, the horizontal tab, for which hardly any font has a glyph.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding

Comment: Why does the title mention a NullPointerException, but the body an IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: @marwn It is good you removed the NPE from the title, but could you also react to the other comments here? After all they do explain why your exception happens. Did that information already allow you to fix the issue or do you still have problems?

Comment: @mkl thanks lot for your feed back, and comments. Anyway as you stated above it might be the horizontal tab what cause the issue, i am trying to test that as i got busy last week, i have not got the chance to test.

Comment: string.replaceAll("\t", " ")  worked fine for me .. thanks lot again ..

Comment: I'll make that an actual answer (in contrast to a mere comment as above) which you can accept so the question will appear answered.

Answer (score 9):

The exception message

> U+0009 ('controlHT') is not available in this font Helvetica (generic: ArialMT) encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

means that the string you draw contains a character for which the font (in particular in its selected encoding) provides no glyph drawing instructions.

It even indicates which character is the culprit: "U+0009 ('controlHT')", i.e. a control character, the horizontal tab. Indeed,  control characters have to be avoided as hardly any font will contain glyphs for them.

As you already have confirmed in the comments to your question

> `string.replaceAll("\t", " ")` worked fine for me

So horizontal tabs seem to have been the only problem characters.

Comment: so far horizontal tabs what cause the problems, yet i do not know if string.replaceAll("\t", " ")  is the idle solution as i have to check every string i am drawing in the pdf..

Comment: @marwn Well, it would be easier if you could make sure that the source you retrieve those strings from only supplies strings with drawable characters. As you have not indicated where you get them from, though, I hardly can guess how to do that exactly.

Comment: my string sources are retrieved from database, mostly the were inserted from a form ..

Comment: Then I would advice sanitizing already the form input. Control characters should not be written into database fields meant for a use as yours.